# All combinations of 2d array chess game

Tags: java, recursion, chess

I am making a program that is calculating the number of possible solutions of a chess game with only bishops and queens. The user can put in the number of queens and bishops, as well as the size of the chess board (rows & columns).

I will call any set of positions for the bishops and the queens on the board a combination. A combination counts as a solution if all squares are attacked (Chess domination problem).

So for example, if the user gives 1 Queen and 3 Bishops, on a 5x5 chess board, a possible solution can be:

```
- - B - -
- - - - -
- B Q B -
- - - - -
- - - - -
```

Now i have trouble making a program that finds all the possible positions of a given set of pieces, without duplicates. Duplicates can occur because the user can give a multiple number of bishops for example. The solution needs to be recursive.

Comment: If you number each square sequentially, the first bishop can go on any square (except the last n(B)-1). The next bishop has to go on a higher numbered square (except the last n(B)-2), and so-on. The first queen can go on any square without a bishop. But the except last rule is more difficult, and it may be easier to not bother - instead allow that you might fail to place the later piece, so reject the board.

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand what you mean? The goal is to loop all the given pieces over the given board. So that every possible array is made with the given pieces. And all the given pieces need to be used. Not every piece is specific so if the user gives 2 Queens, those 2 pieces are handled as the same, so there won't occur any duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show your current solution, but I /assume/ you pick each square for the first piece, then pick each square for the second piece , and continue if the square is still unoccupied. Then repeat for the third, etc.

If the first and second piece are the same type, then this will cause a duplication. First piece in first position, second in second vs first in second position, second in first.

If you have two pieces of the same type, you can just impose an ordering on your positioning the second piece: Do not place the second identical piece at a lower index than the first. This avoids the duplication, but still visits every permutation of positions. You can impose this ordering on more of the same types of piece.

When you have a different type of piece, the two orderings become distinct. If the first and second are different piece types, then First piece in first position, second in second vs first in second position, second in first are distinct cases. However, when you put down the second instance of the new type, you can apply the ordering rule against the first one.

[Alternatively, you can insist that the second piece is placed before the first piece - the outcome is the same]

As a second optimisation, you can observe that if you have 3 bishops and the third must be placed after the other 2, then the first cannot be placed in the last or penultimate squares, so you can optimise your placement of the first one very slightly.

This becomes more complex when this is the second type of piece, and it is possibly not worth doing.

A third optimisation is to keep a list of the available squares. Once a piece is put down, its square is removed from the list, so the list is shorter for placing the next piece, and you don't have to "fail" when you try and put the queen on top of a bishop, as you won't try. You can use the length of this list to simplify the second optimisation.

You can do some clever tricks with std::list::splice to mean that you don't reallocate or duplicate this list as you recurse through the pieces and positions.